# Recursive jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, recursion

I want my function to process the results, then call itself from the `done` callback.

```
function geocode(id) {
    console.log(id + ' geocode');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/customers/' + id + '/geocode',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            id: id,
        }
    }).done(function() {
        var newID = id++;
        console.log(id + ' done.');
        geocode(newID);
    });
}
```

This isn't incrementing though, say if I start it at 1, it just loops on 2 forever. I know it's a pain returning data from ajax, but I've never fully got my head round the nuances

Comment: what do you exactly want? you want response from the ajax request..?

Answer (score 3):

You need to increment the variable before you set it to the value of `newId`:

```
function geocode(id) {
    console.log(id + ' geocode');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/customers/' + id + '/geocode',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            id: id,
        }
    }).done(function() {
        console.log(id + ' done.'); // show this before incrementing
        var newID = ++id; // note the operator order here
        geocode(newID);
    });
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/net7np0e/)

Comment: Does he not need a context?

Comment: Possibly, depending on the scope of `id` and it's use elsewhere in code that isn't shown here.

Comment: @mplungjan Why, the correct context is set as i can see it

Comment: This works perfectly. I need to look into the operators a bit more, I didn't realise there would be a difference between `i++` and `++i`

Comment: `console.log(id + ' done.');` should be set before pre incrementation to get older value

Comment: @Tom glad to help. Here's further reading on the difference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_()

Comment: I am surprised. I would have expected the need for something like `function geocode(id) {  $this=this; $this.id=id; $.ajax({ context:$this,... .....done(function() { this.id++; geocode(this.id); }`

Answer (score -1):

Your id will be 1 on the first iteration, and 1 on the second (and third, fourth etc.) iteration as well as you never update it's value.

Try this:

```
function geocode(id) {
    console.log(id + ' geocode');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/customers/' + id + '/geocode',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            id: id,
        }
    }).done(function() {
        id = id++;
        console.log(id + ' done.');
        geocode(id);
    });
}
```

Comment: This is logically the same as what the OP currently has.